# Property of mutually independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was wondering is the following proposition true or not?

**Proposition:** Let $E=\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a family of mutually independent events and $S_1,\dots,S_k$ be a partition of $E$. Then $$\{\bigcup\limits_{A\in S_j}A\}_{j=1}^k$$ also mutually independent events.

**This is what I have so far.** For each $1\leq j\leq k$ we have $S_j=\{A_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I_j}$. Denote $B_j:=\cup_{\alpha\in I_j}A_{\alpha}$, then our goal to show that $\{B_1,\dots,B_k\}$ are mutually independent events, equivalently for any $t\geq 2$ and $1\leq r_1<\dots<r_t\leq k$ we have $$\text{Pr}[B_{r_1}\cap \dots\cap B_{r_t}]=\text{Pr}[B_{r_1}]\times\dots\times \text{Pr}[B_{r_t}]. \quad \quad (*)$$

Let's consider the RHS of $(*)$.

$$\text{RHS}=\prod_{s=1}^{t}\text{Pr}[B_{r_s}]=\prod_{s=1}^{t}\text{Pr}[\cup_{\alpha\in I_{r_s}}A_{\alpha}]=\prod_{s=1}^{t}(1-\text{Pr}[\cap_{\alpha\in I_{r_s}}\overline{A_{\alpha}}])=$$
$$=\prod_{s=1}^{t}(1-\prod_{\alpha\in I_{r_s}}\text{Pr}[\overline{A_{\alpha}}]),$$
in the last equaility I am using the property that if somefamily of events are mutually independent, then their complements are also mutually independent.

I was trying to simplify the LHS and reduce to the RHS but I failed.

I'd be very thankful for any help!

Comment: Try showing $$P(\bigcap_{s = 1}^t{B_{r_s}^c}) = \prod_{s = 1}^tP(B_{r_s}^c)$$ instead. This is sufficient to conclude independence of $B_1, \dots, B_k$.

Comment: @Mason, indeed if we can prove the equality which you wrote then it implies that events $\{B_1^c,\dots,B_k^c\}$ are mutually independent and hence $\{B_1,\dots,B_k\}$ are mutually independent, right?

Comment: @Mason, but is it easier to prove your equality?